# I want to send array from function with Ajax via JSON

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm trying to send JSON array from function.

My code is:

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ws_categories WHERE parent_id = :parent_id ORDER BY sort_order ASC, name ASC';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(['parent_id' => $parent_id]);
        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo ''.$sub_mark.''.$row['name'].'';
        categoryTree($row['category_id'], $sub_mark.'&ndash; ');
    }
}

$output = array(
    "draw"          =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"          =>  categoryTree()
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

I'm not sure where my code is wrong. Just try to collect all data from the categoryTree() and send it via JSON, but with no success.

Comment: basically `categoryTree()` is a recursive function with no return value. that's why you get nothing

Comment: you need to `return` data from `categoryTree` not `echo`.

Comment: Please check the updated version bellow...

Answer (score 0):

Now show me the categories but only parent ones without subcategories:

```
$output = array();

function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ws_categories WHERE parent_id = :parent_id ORDER BY sort_order ASC, name ASC';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(['parent_id' => $parent_id]);
    $filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();

        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                $sub_array = array();
                $sub_array[] = $sub_mark.$row['name'];
                $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["category_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
                $array[] = $sub_array;
                categoryTree($row['category_id'], $sub_mark.'&ndash; ');
        }
        return $array;
}

$data = categoryTree();

$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

I'm sure that is close to done but I do not know what I missed.